# API - can the authenticate route ever be private?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express

I've been thinking about my API and need some clarification on something.

**Can the authenticate route on an API that is used by a public website ever be private?** 
By authentication route I mean, where I check a username and password is correct to login.

I guess some routes of the API could be private, for example, adding a comment to a photo, a user needs to be logged in and a token etc could be checked.

But I don't see how other routes can be made that way.

So does this mean I could obtain the route of some site and attempt to 'bash' the site with usernames and passwords? How to companies mitigate this - i presume some security would be in place?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to add a middleware in your route to check if the user is logged in.

Comment: Also good module to limit amount of requests for some routes. https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit

Comment: A login route, by definition, cannot be private because you can't yet check auth on the route designed to provide auth credentials.  That would be like putting your front door doorbell on the inside of the house where only those people already inside the house can actually use the doorbell.

Comment: @jfriend00 - thats the analogy I was after. So i guess websites protect themselves from someone mis-using say a login route by some IP limit?

Comment: There are lots and lots of articles written about various techniques for that.  It really depends upon what you're trying to protect against.  People use rate limiting by IP, max wrong guesses by IP/cookie, requiring extra piece of login information after N wrong guesses, temporary account lockout for some period of time after N wrong guesses.  Search "strategies against password attacks" and you will find a ton of articles.

Answer (score 0):

to make a route "private" you need create a middlware to do all necessary validation before doing something

```
function validationFunction(req, res, next) {

    // do any checks you want to in here

    if (can the route proceed) //you decide how to do this
        return next();


    // if the route cannot proceed
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

use it in your route

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/yourRoute', validationFunction, function(req, res) {
        //executes what the route should execute
    });

};
```

if a route is public that means it have no problem being public and all security measures supposedly was taken.

Comment: I'm done something similar already - but my wondering was - an authenticate route on an API that is used by a public website never be private - which i guess is true